# Tokyo's Keikyu Airport Line transit question

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, tokyo, hnd

I will be taking the Keikyu Airport Line from Haneda to Onarimon Station.

According to Google transit it shows the following:

[image]

My question is this, where it has Keikyu Airport Line towards Inzaimakinohara, and then Keikyu Main Line towards Inzaimakinohara (squared off in green), do I need to change trains? Or, is this actually the same train, and it's just broken up on the transit directions?

Not sure if it will help, but here is the link to the Google maps with the transit: [maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Haneda+Airport+International+Terminal+Station,+Tokyo,+Japan/Onarimon+Station,+Tokyo,+Japan/@35.6137519,139.7461115,12z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m19!4m18!1m5!1m1!1s0x60186156b2f277b1:0xc59dac631427bf6c!2m2!1d139.767021!2d35.54506!1m5!1m1!1s0x60188bbfe5f5e897:0x626dfab60e48e775!2m2!1d139.751535!2d35.661215!2m4!4e3!6e4!7e2!8j1429205400!3e3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the [Keikyū Airport Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keiky%C5%AB_Airport_Line) is the 6.5km stretch from Haneda to Keikyū Kamada, at which the line changes name and becomes [Keikyū Main Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keiky%C5%AB_Main_Line). Since [the Airport Line offers Airport Express service](http://www.haneda-tokyo-access.com/en/transport/trainlinemap.html) from Haneda to your destination, you shouldn't have to change train at Kamada. Moreover this is reflected in the screenshot you posted which all in all seems to suggest only a line name change rather than an actual connection.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the information. I would have never thought to check Wikipedia for train lines. Thanks again.